# How can I test an AlarmManager.setRepeating?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm creating an alarm using AlarmManager, it works great, but I'd like to test the .setRepeating method, which I setup like this:

```
Calendar calMon = Calendar.getInstance();

calMon.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

calMon.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tPicker.getCurrentHour());
calMon.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tPicker.getCurrentMinute());
calMon.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calMon.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calMon.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, newIntent(this, Calendar.MONDAY));

public static PendingIntent newIntent(Context context, int dayId){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("myApp.intent.action.CLOCK");

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, dayId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Let's say the alarm it setup to repeat every monday at 2pm, the first alarm on monday starts correctly, if I want to test the next week alarm, I go to settings and move the date to the next monday and the time at 1:58pm, to see if it works when it reaches 2pm, however, right after I change the settings, the alarm starts before 2pm.

I'd like to know if there's a more accurate way to test the .setRepeating or if there's something in my configuration that is not working. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the comments provided, I got it work by adding 7 in the calculation, so I was able to test the alarm by modifying the date and time in the phone in one week:

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calMon.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, newIntent(this, Calendar.MONDAY));
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Let's say the alarm it setup to repeat every monday at 2pm" -- note that this is not the code that you have here. You have it repeating daily.

Comment: I think this is one option you have to test it for now or either you can convert it to repeat every five minutes just for testing

Comment: As Mark said, you have your alarm set to repeat daily, this means that if you move the time to next Sunday (and the alarm wants to fire **tomorrow**), it will fire as soon as possible after the date it is set to... so, you have your "issue" (which is by design).

Comment: It worked by adding 7 to the next week calculation, thanks!